# Javascript global object when not in browser

Tags: javascript

I have the following script which works fine in a browser but not when running on a ASP script where there is no "window" for the global object. How do I change it to use the global object and not window?

```
var $ = {}

$.namespace = function() {
    var a=arguments, o=null, i, j, d;
    for (i=0; i<a.length; i=i+1) {
        d=a[i].split(".");
        o=window;
        for (j=0; j<d.length; j=j+1) {
            o[d[j]]=o[d[j]] || {};
            o=o[d[j]];
        }
    }
    return o;
};
```

This enabled me to go:

```
$.namespace("myApp.test");
myApp.test.myString = "hello world";
```

thanks

Comment: I don't know about asp script but in node.js there is `global` variable so you can use `o=window||global;`

Comment: Do you want to declare a variable out of window scope??

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this code

```
var $ = {}
var $this = this;
$.namespace = function() {
    var a=arguments, o=null, i, j, d;
    for (i=0; i<a.length; i=i+1) {
        d=a[i].split(".");
        o=$this;
        for (j=0; j<d.length; j=j+1) {
            o[d[j]]=o[d[j]] || {};
            o=o[d[j]];
        }
    }
    return o;
};
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt explain the usage of the function. I've edited my original post, my apologies. Your solution didnt work with the final line myApp.test.myString = "hello world"; Although the $.namespace("myApp.test"); at least ran cleanly. Thanks

Comment: You can use "this" to refrence global object. It will be better if you share what output you are looking for. I have updated the code.